# Direct3D YUV Formats?

Tags: c++, video, direct3d, yuv, dxgi

How do the [YUV texture formats in Direct3D 11 for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) work? The documentation is a bit sparse and I haven't found any examples.

When reading from such textures in a shader, will `texture.rgb` be the same as `.yuv` or does an automatic conversion occur? And if so what conversion is used ([ITU-R BT.601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion)) SD or ([ITU-R BT.701](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.709_conversion)) HD or does it automatically choose based on the texture size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct3D does not perform YUV color-space conversion. Refer to the DXGI_FORMAT page (linked in your question) for the mapping.  For example:

> **DXGI_FORMAT_AYUV**
>   ...
>   The mapping to the view channel is V->R8, U->G8, Y->B8, and A->A8.

Comment: which format for yuv420?